# Is there a function in any Jenkins API that provides me with a slave nodes COMPUTERNAME/Hostname

Tags: python, api, jenkins, jenkins-api

I need to get together a list of all the hostnames of the jenkins slave nodes set up on my jenkins master node. Many of the nodes are set up with names like `SLAVE NODE EXAMPLE` instead of having their server name as the name of the node. I know how to get to this from the UI. However I need to access this through python as I have many nodes set up and it will be a long process to manually go through each one.

I am using the python-jenkins api which has a function that gets me all the nodes and their configurations. using `get_node_config(name)`. However it does not provide me with the `COMPUTERNAME`. I can't seem to find the file that contains that information int the Jenkins Home directory either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a groovy script if that helps. Run from the console. Note: nodes must be on-line to query.

```
Jenkins.instance.slaves.each {
   print it.getNodeName() + ' : '
   if ( it.getComputer().isOnline() ) {
      println it.getComputer().getHostName() + ' : ' + it.getComputer().getOSDescription()
   } else {
      println ' - offline -'
   }    
}
return 0
```

See Jenkins API - [Computer](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Computer.html)

Comment: This is great. Thanks!

Comment: If it works great, consider marking as answered (even tho not python).

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the node name you can use that name to get more info about the with 
[get_node_info(name, depth=0)](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jenkins.Jenkins.get_node_info)

```
nodes = get_nodes()
for n in nodes:
   info = get_node_info(n[name])
```